# VBA Index/Match with multiple criteria (unique value & date)

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that has values for more than one month, so I am trying to first find the value based on a value in the wsRevFile worksheet and then ensure that this is the value from last month. When I use the following code, I get a "invalid number of arguments" error.

```
Sub RevLookup(wsMvFile As Worksheet, wsRevOld As Worksheet, wsNewRev As Worksheet, _
                        rowCount As Integer, workCol As String, _
                        srcCol1 As Integer, srcCol2 As Integer)

Dim vrw As Variant, i As Long

For i = 2 To rowCount
    vrw = Application.Match(wsRevFile.Range("A" & i), wsNewRev.Columns(2), Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0), "mm/dd/yyyy"), wsNewRev.Columns(1), 0)
    If IsError(vrw) Then
        vrw = Application.Match(wsRevFile.Range("A" & i), wsRevOld.Columns(1), 0)
        If Not IsError(vrw) Then _
            wsRevFile.Range(workCol & i) = Application.Index(wsRevOld.Columns(srcCol1), vrw)
    Else
        wsRevFile.Range(workCol & i) = Application.Index(wsNewRev.Columns(srcCol2), vrw, 1)
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

I am assuming this has to do with the way I assigned the Application Match function, because the formula without this part works for other columns. Any ideas on how I could get this to work?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: application.WorksheetFunction.Match(wsRevFile.Range("A" & i),wsNewRev.Columns(2),0)

Comment: The Match function only allows three In your first you have 5

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Addint the `WorksheetFunction` Will not allow it to pass an error the variable and will stop the code if the value is not found.

Comment: @ScottCraner Does that mean I have to add a second match function in order to validate the date?

Comment: application.Match(wsRevFile.Range("A" & i),wsNewRev.Columns(2),0)

Comment: No that will not work because they will be independent of each other, where you are wanting where both are true.  At this point it would be worth moving everything into variant array and cycling through them instead.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav Yes, this works, but I does not validate the date, before pulling the data.

Comment: You could use the match result to be the 2nd search, so match in A1:A100 say gives a return of 65, then match on A65:A100 for the 2nd ?  something like this, NOT TESTED, `application.match("DATE",range("A" & application.match("VALUE",range("A1:A100"),0) & ":A100",0)`

Comment: @ScottCraner Do you have an example of what an array search would like that would look like? That's something I haven't done before.

Comment: no promises on this but try: `Application.Match(1, (wsRevFile.Range("A" & i) = wsNewRev.Columns(2)) * (Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0), "mm/dd/yyyy")), 0)`

Comment: Unfortunately this gives me an object error, but thanks for the suggestion. Let me dig into the variant array and see if I can come up with something.

Comment: have you tried application.match("DATE",range("A" & application.match("VALUE",range("A1:A100"),0) & ":A100",0)

Comment: @Nathan_Sav No, I could not get it to work either.

Comment: vrw = Application.Match(Format(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date), 0), "mm/dd/yyyy"), Range("A" & Application.Match("VALUE", wsRevFile.Range("A" & i), 0) & wsRevFile.Range("A" & i), 0))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try ajusting the variables of the following procedure, as I didn't figure out your input and output data:

```
Sub Main()
Dim SearchValue As Variant
Dim SearchColumn As Range
Dim ReturnColumn As Range
Dim ResultRows As Collection
Dim LastDate As Variant 'Date?
Dim iRow As Variant

SearchValue = 10 '<-- change to suit
Set SearchColumn = wsNewRev.Range("B1:B10")
Set ReturnColumn = wsNewRev.Range("C1:C10") '<-- change to suit

Set ResultRows = GetLoopRows(SearchColumn, SearchValue)
For Each iRow In ResultRows
    If LastDate < ReturnColumn(iRow) Then
        LastDate = ReturnColumn(iRow)
    End If
Next iRow

Debug.Print LastDate
End Sub

Function GetLoopRows(ParamArray pParameters() As Variant) As Collection
'Obtém limites de laços com levando em conta condições
'[vetor1], [valor1], [vetor2], [valor2], ...

Dim iCondition As Long
Dim i As Variant
Dim iRow As Variant
Dim Result As Collection
Dim NumConditions As Long
Dim SearchCollection As Collection
Dim ArraysCollection As Collection
Dim iArray As Variant

NumConditions = (UBound(pParameters) - LBound(pParameters) + 1) / 2
Set ArraysCollection = New Collection
Set SearchCollection = New Collection
For i = LBound(pParameters) To UBound(pParameters) Step 2
    ArraysCollection.Add pParameters(i + 0).Value2
    SearchCollection.Add pParameters(i + 1)
Next i

Set Result = New Collection
For iRow = LBound(ArraysCollection(1)) To UBound(ArraysCollection(1))
    For iCondition = 1 To NumConditions
        If ArraysCollection(iCondition)(iRow, 1) <> SearchCollection(iCondition) Then GoTo Continue
    Next iCondition
    Result.Add CLng(iRow)
Continue:
Next iRow
Quit:
Set GetLoopRows = Result
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Felipe, but I cannot get the code to run in my workbook, because I don't understand how to amend it. What value needs to be entered for the SearchValue? And how does the code identify the correct date?

Comment: I was very sick, sorry for delay.
Well, you basically put the value you want to search at the variable `SearchValue`, and set which column you want to search by changing `SearchColumn` range address and the same for `ReturnColumn`.

Comment: Thanks Felipe, this is exactly what I was after!